# How to recieve from private function and run in another function with if statement

Tags: php

How I can check value what I get from other private function.

Lets say I have `processCategory()` function and I want check if this category name already exists with other function what is private like `checkCategory()`.

I've tryied but my if statement doesn't check if it exists or not and still processing to database.

My `processCategory()` function:

```
/**
* Content::processCategory()
* 
* @return
*/

public function processCategory()
{
    $rules = array(
        'category' => array('required|string|min_len,3|max_len,60', Lang::$word->CATEGORY),
        'active' => array('required|numeric', Lang::$word->PUBLISHED),
    );

    $validate = Validator::instance();
    $safe = $validate->doValidate($_POST, $rules);

    if ($this->checkCategory($safe->category, 'check') == "true") {
        Message::msgSingleError("Category name already exists");
    }

    if (empty(Message::$msgs)) { //it should not process this if category name already exists in database.
        //NOTE: At the moment it still processing category name

    $data = array(
        'name' => $safe->category,
        'author' => App::Auth()->name,
        'active' => $safe->active,
    );

    (Filter::$id) ? Db::run()->update(self::cpTable, $data, array("id" => Filter::$id)) : Db::run()->insert(self::cpTable, $data)->start(); 

    $message = Filter::$id ? Message::formatSuccessMessage($data['name'], Lang::$word->NW_UPDATE_OK) : Message::formatSuccessMessage($data['name'], Lang::$word->NW_ADDED_OK);

    Message::msgReply(Db::run()->affected(), 'success', $message);
    } else {
    Message::msgSingleStatus();
    }
}
```

My `checkCategory()` function:

```
/**
* Content::checkCategory()
* 
* @return
*/

private function checkCategory($name, $type)
{   
    switch ($type) {
    case "insert":
        if (!$row = Db::run()->first(self::cpTable, null, array("name =" => $name))) {
            return $this->insertCategory($name);
        } else {
            return $row->id;
        }
        break;

    case "check":
        $count = Db::run()->select(self::cpTable, null, array("name =" => $name))->results(); 
        return (count($count) > 1) ? 'true' : 'false';
        break;
    }
}
```

Types:

`$type = "insert"` - for project inserting. It checks if category exists or not - if not then inserts category.

`$type = "check"` - for category. It should just check if exists or not. If exists then should send data true and then other function should stop processing and give me error message.

Comment: `> 1` should be `> 0`. Your check only returns true when there are at least two rows with the name.

Comment: @Barmar thanks got working :)